# Изменить регулярное выражение чтоб пропускало 10 цифр или одну цифру "0"

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

В большом регулярном выражении есть такой участок он проверят строку в JS

```
...,"a20":\d{10},"a21":1,...
```

\d{10}

проверяет чтоб было 10 цифр подряд. А как изменить этот участок чтоб он пропускал строку, если в ней окажется 10 цифр или только одна цифра "0". Как изменить этот участок регулярного выражения?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чем сложность:  

    ...,"a20":^0$|\d{10},"a21":1,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\d{10} означает что должно быть ровно 10 цифр, но можно варьировать этот параметр например так \d{1,10} и теперь проверка допустит даже наличие 1-й цифры.

Если нужно рассматривать 2 варианта - или 10 цифр или цифра 0 то можно сделать вот так:
заменить \d{10} на (\d{1,10}|0). Протестировать можно тут - http://regex101.com/r/yK8nZ5

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, тут дали в комментариях ответ, который работает (?:\d{10}|0) но почему то сразу его удалили. Символы "?:", что то меняют?

Comment: @Gennady, удалил его потому, что внимательнее вчитался в задачу, у вас там не стоит условие "или", а вариант простой замены 10 цифр на 0 был предложен уже до меня.

Что касается '?:' - это команда "не запоминать", т.к. по умолчанию то, что между скобками, "запоминается". Добавил эту конструкцию на случай, если у вас уже стоят круглые скобки в выражении и вы в дальнейшем обрабатываете запомненные значения

Comment: Да, я извиняюсь за не точность. В заголовке вопроса я указал "или", а в описании ограничился "Если", а оно не так явно указывает но то что мне нужно, чтоб работали оба варианта. Сейчас все поправил, всем спасибо!